# Casting to varchar using Subsonic 2.2

Tags: subsonic, subsonic2.2

How can I reproduce

```
SELECT CAST(ID AS varchar(20)) AS IdAsString
FROM Table
```

Using Subsonic 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've generated classes from the database, something like this:

```
TableCollection tc = new TableCollection ();
TableCollection.Load();
string s = "";
foreach (Table t in tc) {
    s += " " + t.ID.ToString();
}
```

I'm assuming you want the whole table, otherwise you'd probably have the ID to start with.
You can also use

```
TableCollection.WHERE("OtherColumn", 23).Load();
```

to retrict the table records returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
DAL.DB.Select(
    string.Format("CAST({0} AS varchar(20)) AS IdAsString", DAL.Table.Columns.ID)
    )
.From<DAL.Table>()
...
```